# Simplify string iteration

Tags: c, loops

I'm at the very beginning of learning to code (specifically C).
While writing a function which is counting the chars of an array for studying purposes, I was questioning myself (and I'm pretty sure about it), if there is the possibility to simplify this iteration:

```
int stringlength(char* s)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (s != NULL && *(s + i) != '\0')
        i++;

    return i;
}
```

I would like to keep the `i++` within the iteration itself (for loop?).

I'm appreciating any hint you guys got for me. If you find something question unrelated which I'm doing wrong - please let me know.

Comment: You can extract the check for `s != NULL` into an `if` condition at the beginning at the function

Comment: Note that functions whose names start with `strx` where `x` is a lower-case letter are a bad idea, that whole space of names is reserved for the standard library. This particular function should be safe, though since we already have `strlen()`. :)

Comment: Thanks for the hints :) Thinking about extracting {s != NULL}, am I extracting this check only for performance reasons (not checking for the same every char of the array)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest using pointers arithmetic.

First, handle the `NULL` case (empty string, hence you only get the null terminator). Otherwise, iterate on the pointer and increment the counter. Then, simply return that counter.

```
int stringlength(char* s)
{
   if (!s) return 0;
   int len = 0;

   while (*s++) len++;

   return len;
}
```

What's the magic with the `(*s++)` ?
Well this is equivalent to *(s++) != 0. But because `++` has a higher precedence than `*`, the parenthesis are useless.

Also, you can have a look on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733281/strlen-implementation-in-gcc).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you let me know why creating a copy of the source pointer is useful/necessary? Also, if you find some time to explain some more, how exactly is the condition of "while" working in this case? *cp++ is checking for the "next" char in the string, but why exactly is the condition (*cp++) finding to an end if I'm not checking for "\0"?

Comment: @hiimvinzent I will edit the response. The copy is not needed here, indeed.

Comment: @YassineHoussni: did you try it?

Comment: I did compile it without copying but using this iteration and it works fine for me. As I'm only checking for the value and not changing it, I assume copying is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(s == NULL)
    return 0;
int i;
for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++);
```

This should solve your purpose, I believe.

**EDIT:** Adding a NULL check for the input `char*` since `NULL` could be a possible value.

Answer (score 2):

```
int stringlength(char* s)
{
    if (!s) 
       return 0;
    int i = -1;
    while(s[++i]!='\0');
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code answers, also provide some commentary on what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I tested `strlen(NULL)` of `glibc`, it causes `Segment Fault` and I think it is reasonable to cause `Segment Fault`. So here is my implementation:

```
#include <assert.h>

int stringlength(const char* s) {
    assert(s != NULL);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i]; ++i);

    return i;
}
```

Note: `s` is `const char *`, but not `char *`.